# Magento Search is Slow after 1.9.3 Upgrade

Tags: php, magento, search, catalog

Since we upgraded to Magento 1.9.3, we noticed that the search results take well over 10 seconds to load. We implemented noticed 1.9.3 search fixes on other threads, but it didn't help. We see that the Advanced Search works fine, but its the regular search that takes forever.

We ran a test on our development environment: we reverted the 1.9.3 update back to the 1.9.2.3 version for the following files:

- `app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Resource/Fulltext.php`
- `app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Resource/Fulltext/Collection.php`
- `app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Resource/Helper/Mysql4.php`

The search results loaded in around 5-6 seconds. Has anyone else had slow load times when using search after the update?

Also, what kind of issues can we run into by reverting these? Are there security holes?

I'm asking because I don't know if Magento will come out with anything soon and if they do, will it fix the slow search results we're getting? It's the holiday season and our stores need to function as fast as possible.

I hope someone else has a solution, some notes, or anything else so any other people having this issue can pick up some tips.

Answer (score 0):

Here the search returns 0 items after update to 1.9.3.1
The problem is inside:

app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Resource/Fulltext.php

I restored a previous version too

Comment: I'm having the same problem, restoring to 1.9.3 didn't worked for me. For what version have you restored yours?